# How to check if optional protocol function is implemented pure swift?

Tags: swift

I have a Pure swift struct which cannot use @obc in protocol declaration

```
// Struct is very heavy on processing to create
struct HugeDataStruct {
   ....
}

protocol MyOptionalProtocol: class {
   func frameWork(_ framework: Framework, willProcess data: HugeDataStruct)
}

extension MyOptionalProtocol {
   func frameWork(_ framework: Framework, willProcess data: HugeDataStruct) {}
}
```

Now here is where the problem is. I would like to do the massive processing only if the delegate has implemented the optional protocol function.

```
// Somewhere else in my framework
func callDelegateFuncOnlyIfImplemented() { 
   let hugeDataStruct: HugeDataStruct = doSomeMassiveProcessing()
   frameworkDelegate?.frameWork(_ framework: self, willProcess data: hugeDataStruct
}
```

Is there any way to detect if the delegate has implemented the optional function **before** i do the massive processing?

Comment: What "optional protocol function"? There is no "optional protocol function". All functions within a non-ObjC protocol are mandatory.

Comment: "optional" as in -> if the developer uses the framework, he can optionally implement the function (if you get what i mean).

Comment: In the code you posted, you don't need to check if the delegate implemented the protocol method, you only need to see if the delegate is nil or not.

Comment: the delegate is needed for the framework to work.
therefore the delegate will be almost 100% implemented if checked.
i know the delegate will be implemented.
i just want to know if it will implement _that_ function

Comment: @swiftnub So your question is if you can find out whether the protocol implementor overrides the protocol-extension implementation? If the implementor implements the functions it will be used if the first class who conforms in the inheritance-chain implements too(incase you have a inheritance hierarchy, if not then if implemented that will be used). Or is `frameworkDelegate` some class but you want to find out whether it conforms to `MyOptionalProtocol?` You can do that with `guard let conformingDelegate = frameworkDelegate as? MyOptionalFramework else {return }`.

Comment: @Purpose i am trying to find out if `frameworkDelegate` (the protocol implementer) has overridden the protocol function. And **only** if it has overridden the function -> then i want to do the heavy processing.

Comment: @swiftnub I’ve never heard of that possibility. You could declare the protocol function as throwing, throw an error there and catch the error to see whether the delegate implemented the function. It’s only after-the-fact checking though. That API sounds like a mess. You could try Objc-Protocols where Optional functions are possible.

Comment: You could wrap the do-catch in a wrapper though with completion blocks, or return a `Bool` to say whether the delegate implemented or not.

Comment: As Purpose said, this looks like poor API design. Could you give us more information on `HugeDataStruct`, `MyOptionalProtocol`, and `doSomeMassiveProcessing`, so perhaps we can suggest something better?

Comment: I do not think this is poor design. In my real framework, (just as inThe example above), I have an optionalDelegate function which classes can conform to. The processing of the data in that delegate is a little heavy. Therefore i would not want to process the heavy data unnecessarily especially is theFunction is not implemented. ThisIs a veryCommonSituation. The contents of `doSomeMassiveProcessing` does not matter much. It is just a func that takes a while to execute. `HugeDataStruct` simply stores thedata from `doSomeMassiveProcessing` and `MyOptionalProtocol` is a protocolWithSaidFunction.

Comment: If you would like to know the real case, it is used in [This](https://github.com/patchthecode) library. On the delegate function `scrollViewWillEndDragging` i do some calculations and then call the delegate function with the result of the calculations. But, i do not want to do the calculations if the function is not implemented because the calculations (depending on how the developer designs the calendar) may case the screen frame rate to drop.